# Linear Algebra: Eigenvalue Proof Question

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Does anyone know how to prove that eigenvalues (including multiplicities) of a triangular matrix coincides with its diagonal entries?
Thank you so much!

Comment: There is a proof in Axler for instance. It avoids determinants.

Comment: Hint: what is the determinant of a diagonal matrix?

Comment: @lhf thanks so much, do you know where I could find that proof?

Comment: You can take a look at this lesson: http://lem.ma/vC You will learn something from each of the videos in that lesson, but the very last video deals with a triangular matrix.

Answer (score 1):

> All diagonal entries are eigenvalues

Proof by induction on the order $n$ of the matrix.
$n=1$ is easy.

For $n>1$, by induction, $a_{11}, a_{22}, \dots a_{n-1,n-1}$ are eigenvalues of $A$. Now the last row of $A-a_{nn}I$ is all zeros and so $A-a_{nn}I$ does not full rank. This implies that the kernel of $A-a_{nn}I$ is not trivial and so $a_{nn}$ is an eigenvalue.

> All eigenvalues appear in the diagonal

If $\lambda$ is does not appear in the diagonal, then $B=A-\lambda I$ does not have any zero in the diagonal and so $Bx=b$ can be solved for all $b$. This means that $B$ is invertible and so $B$ is injective. In other words, the kernel of $B=A-\lambda I$ is $0$ and $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$.